# MP charts RTL not working android

Tags: android, right-to-left

I am working with in a multilingual application where I am using MP charts(charting library) for statistics display. But in Rtl layouts its not mirroring to Rtl direction. Is there way I may get it working for Rtl layout?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done but there is a way to implement that by inversing your values like add higher values first e.g if you are making graph on x-axis of values 1,2,3,4 just reverse the order add 4 on first index and 1 on last index. By doing this it will draw from left to right but it looks like from left to right also disable left axis and enable right axis so graph looks like it.